# How to customize <input type="file">?

Tags: html, css, file-upload, input

Is it possible to change the appearance of `<input type="file">`?

Comment: The reason the text field is there is because it shows the user the file path after they browse and select their file.

Comment: Oooppss.. it seems that its the way Firefox handles it...

Comment: Just so we're clear, even after they browse for the file, they still have to submit the form with a form submit button.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can’t modify much about the `input[type=file]` control itself.

Since clicking a `label` element correctly paired with an input will activate/focus it, we can use a `label` to trigger the OS browse dialog.

Here is how you can do it…

```css
label {
   cursor: pointer;
   /* Style as you please, it will become the visible UI component. */
}

#upload-photo {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<label for="upload-photo">Browse...</label>
<input type="file" name="photo" id="upload-photo" />
```

The CSS for the form control will make it appear invisible and not take up space in the document layout, but will still *exist* so it can be activated via the `label`.

If you want to display the user’s chosen path after selection, you can listen for the `change` event with JavaScript and then read the path that the browser makes available to you (for security reasons it can *lie* to you about the exact path). A way to make it pretty for the end user is to simply use the base name of the path that is returned (so the user simply sees the chosen filename).

There is a [great guide by Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) for styling this.

Comment: I believe, these are better styles, considering we aim for select file dialog to be opened by clicking anywhere on the container: `#container { position: relative; width: ...px; height: ...px; overflow: hidden; } #input { position: absolute; right: 0; font-size: <many a>px; opacity: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }`

Comment: [Using `<label>` (as shown by Tympanus)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is far more semantic and less hacky. Also, this question was asked again a few years later and has much better answers there: [cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I agree, if I can remember correctly (back in 2011) it had problems with IE, probably 6 or 7. I will edit this answer to bring it into the future now.

Comment: Why would it be better to use label? You cannot tab labels, besides, a button makes more sense to me than a label to activate a dialog.

Comment: Created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anqd1h2j/) for this in case anyone wants to play around with it.

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews A `label` automatically triggers the dropdown, even if JS is disabled. Which was more a concern back in 2011 I guess. A `button` is probably the better choice now.

Comment: @alex, It's not displaying the file name.

Answer (score 39):

Something like that maybe?

```
<form>
  <input id="fileinput" type="file" style="display:none;"/>
</form>
<button id="falseinput">El Cucaratcha, for example</button>
<span id="selected_filename">No file selected</span>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#falseinput').click(function(){
    $("#fileinput").click();
  });
});
$('#fileinput').change(function() {
  $('#selected_filename').text($('#fileinput')[0].files[0].name);
});

</script>
```

Comment: In this case ie 9 won't allow to send the form to iframe.

Comment: @x-yuri what do you mean?

Comment: As far as I remember, ie 9 (and probably others) won't allow to send the form to iframe, because user didn't click the input-file.

Comment: `display: none` will remove the input from tab order, making the page less accessible. [Using `<label>` (as shown by Tympanus)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is far more semantic and less hacky. Also, this question was asked again a few years later and has much better answers there: [cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button).

Comment: fixed closing square bracket typo in a selector to make the code actually work

Answer (score 32):

```
  <label for="fusk">dsfdsfsd</label>
  <input id="fusk" type="file" name="photo" style="display: none;">
```

why not? ^_^

See the example [here](https://jsbin.com/runari)

Comment: @InakiIbarrolaAtxa can you provide data to support this?

Comment: Doesn't style anything in Chrome 51. [Using `<label>` (as shown by Tympanus)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is a semantically correct solution. Also, this question was asked again a few years later and has much better answers there: [cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button).

Answer (score 21):

If you're using **Bootstrap** here is a better solution:

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" style="display: none;" required>
</label>
```

**For IE8 and below:** https://www.abeautifulsite.net/posts/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/#legacy-approach-(ie8-and-below)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164555/625952

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this, using bootstrap. On the phone, the form was submitting whenever I clicked the tick that completed the photo, **without the photo**, rather than waiting for the submit button. Currently I have:  `<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    <input onchange="alert('Please check picture is OK')";  type="file" required>
</label>`and some javascript to check required fields, as the bootstrap examples.

Answer (score 16):

Easiest way..

```
<label>
     Upload
    <input type="file" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
</label>
```

Comment: with `style="display:none;"` it's much better tahn visibility:hidden

Answer (score 13):

The trick is hide the input and customize the label.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="inputfile-box">
  <input type="file" id="file" class="inputfile" onchange='uploadFile(this)'>
  <label for="file">
    <span id="file-name" class="file-box"></span>
    <span class="file-button">
      <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Select File
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inputfile-box {
  position: relative;
}

.inputfile {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.file-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(2rem - 2px);
}

.file-button {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
function uploadFile(target) {
    document.getElementById("file-name").innerHTML = target.files[0].name;
}
```

You can check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/rjurado/hnf0zhy1/4/

Answer (score 10):

In webkit you can try this out...

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button{
   /* style goes here */
}
```

Comment: do you know any similar solution for firefox ? Does it exist ? )

Answer (score 7):

first of all it's a container:

```
<div class="upload_file_container">
    Select file!
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
</div>
```

The second, it's a CSS style, if you want to real more customization, just keeping your eyes is open :)

```
.upload_file_container{
   width:100px;
   height:40px;
   position:relative;
   background(your img);
}

.upload_file_container input{
   width:100px;
   height:40px;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

This example hasn't style for text inside the button, it depends on font-size, just correct the height and padding-top values for container

Comment: I wonder why don't you make it `right: 0`, instead of `left: 0`? That way you would have ie's text box out of the container. Clicking on text box doen't open select file dialog. Also, I believe making input file big with `font-size` is much better idea, then using `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick pure CSS workaround (works on chrome and has a FireFox fallback included), including the file name,a label and an custom upload button, does what it should - no need for JavaScript at all!

Note: ☝ anyways, I would not use it on a real world website - if browser compatibility is a thing to you (what it should be). So it's more kind of experimental, otherwise while time goes by, it could be that this isn't an issue today.

```css
.fileUploadInput {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }
  
  .fileUploadInput label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: setColor(primary, 0.5);
    background: setColor(white);
    transition: .4s ease;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: regular; }
    
  .fileUploadInput input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 gap(m);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #323262;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: regular; }
    .fileUploadInput input[type="file"] {
      padding: 0 gap(m); }
      .fileUploadInput input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 0; }
        
  .fileUploadInput button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 0;
    user-select: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #323262;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 800; }
    .fileUploadInput button svg {
      width: auto;
      height: 50%; }

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  user-select: text;
  line-height: 1.333em; }

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(66, 50, 98, 0.05); }

.container {
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(66, 50, 98, 0.35);
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: white; }

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.fileUploadInput button{
    display: none
}
}
```

```html
<!-- Author: Ali Soueidan-->
<!-- Author URI: https//: www.alisoueidan.com-->

<div class="container">
    <div class="fileUploadInput">
    <label>✨ Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" />
    <button>+</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect and by far the best that I have seen. Quick question, is there a way to  not show the entire file name, for example if the file name is too long  it goes over the "+"

Comment: @ReneChan You can set the 'overflow' with CSS to 'ellipsis' or 'hidden' on the filename.

Answer (score 5):

#### Bootstrap example

```
<label className="btn btn-info btn-lg">
  Upload
  <input type="file" style="display: none" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

to show path of selected file you can try this 
on html :

```
<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" class="file">
</div>
```

and in javascript :

```
        var fakeFileUpload = document.createElement('div');
        fakeFileUpload.className = 'fakefile';
        var image = document.createElement('div');
        image.className='fakebtn';
        image.innerHTML = 'browse';
        fakeFileUpload.appendChild(image);
        fakeFileUpload.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            if (x[i].type != 'file') continue;
            if (x[i].parentNode.className != 'fileinputs') continue;
            x[i].className = 'file hidden';
            var clone = fakeFileUpload.cloneNode(true);
            x[i].parentNode.appendChild(clone);
            x[i].relatedElement = clone.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            x[i].onchange = x[i].onmouseout = function () {
                this.relatedElement.value = this.value;
            }
        }
```

and style :

```
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 370px;
}
input.file.hidden {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
div.fakefile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    width: 370px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 90%;
}
div.fakefile input {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #ccc;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 241px;
    height: 20px;
}
div.fakefile .fakebtn{
    width: 150px;
    background: #eb5a41;
    z-index: 10;
    font-family: roya-bold;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
div.fileinputs input[type="file"]:hover + div .fakebtn{
    background: #DA472E;
}

div.fileinputs input[type="file"] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 102px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's much better if you just use a `<label>`, hide the `<input>`, and customize the label.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="input">
<label for="input" id="label">Choose File</label>
```

CSS:

```
input#input{
    display: none;
}
label#label{
    /* Customize your label here */
}
```

Comment: `display: none` will remove the element from the tab order. [Using `<label>` (as shown by Tympanus)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is the semantically correct way, but needs some refinements. Also, this question was asked again a few years later and has much better answers there: [cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button).

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mousemove(function () {
        $('#myList').css('display', 'block');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $("#hidebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
        $("#myList").html('');
        var fileArray1 = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input');
        for (var i = 0; i < fileArray1.length; i++) {
            var files = fileArray1[i].files;
            for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                $("#myList").append("<li style='color:black'>" + files[j].name + "</li>");
            }
        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) != '') {
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'green');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'green');
            $('#displayFileNames').html($("#myList").children().length + ' ' + 'files selezionato');

        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) == '') {
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');
            $('#displayFileNames').append('Nessun File Selezionato');
        };
    });

  });

  function choosefiles(obj) {
        $(obj).hide();
        $('#myList').css('display', 'none');
        $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
        $("#upload-form").append("<input class='file-input inputs' type='file' onclick='choosefiles(this)' name='file[]' multiple='multiple' />");
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
    }

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#unselect').click(function () {
            $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
            $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
            $('#displayFileNames').html('');
            $("#myList").html('');
            $('#myFileInput').val('');
            document.getElementById('upload-form').reset();         
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');

        });
    });
```

```css
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  .divs {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .inputs {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        height: 2%;
        width: 15%;
        opacity: 0;
        background: #00f;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .icons {
        position: absolute;
    }

 </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div>
                <form id='upload-form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                   
                    <div class="divs" id="divforfile" style="color:black">
                        <input id='myFileInput' class='file-input inputs' type='file' name='file[]' onclick="choosefiles(this)" multiple='multiple' />
                        <i class="material-icons" id="attach" style="font-size:21px;color:black">attach_file</i><label>Allegati</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />  
            <div>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="seebtn"><p>Files &#9660;</p></button>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="hidebtn"><p>Files &#9650;</p></button>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="unselect" style="display:none;float:left">
                    <span style="color:red">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div id="displayFileNames">
                </div>
                <ul id="myList"></ul>
            </div>
```

This is my fully functional customerized file upload/Attachment using jquery & javascript (Visual studio). This will be useful !

Code will be available at the comment section !

Link : https://youtu.be/It38OzMAeig

Enjoy :)

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mousemove(function () {
        $('#myList').css('display', 'block');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $("#hidebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
        $("#myList").html('');
        var fileArray1 = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input');
        for (var i = 0; i < fileArray1.length; i++) {
            var files = fileArray1[i].files;
            for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                $("#myList").append("<li style='color:black'>" + files[j].name + "</li>");
            }
        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) != '') {
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'green');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'green');
            $('#displayFileNames').html($("#myList").children().length + ' ' + 'files selezionato');

        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) == '') {
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');
            $('#displayFileNames').append('Nessun File Selezionato');
        };
    });

  });

  function choosefiles(obj) {
        $(obj).hide();
        $('#myList').css('display', 'none');
        $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
        $("#upload-form").append("<input class='file-input inputs' type='file' onclick='choosefiles(this)' name='file[]' multiple='multiple' />");
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
    }

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#unselect').click(function () {
            $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
            $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
            $('#displayFileNames').html('');
            $("#myList").html('');
            $('#myFileInput').val('');
            document.getElementById('upload-form').reset();         
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');

        });
    });
```

```css
<style>
  .divs {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .inputs {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        height: 2%;
        width: 15%;
        opacity: 0;
        background: #00f;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .icons {
        position: absolute;
    }

 </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```html
   <div>
                <form id='upload-form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                   
                    <div class="divs" id="divforfile" style="color:black">
                        <input id='myFileInput' class='file-input inputs' type='file' name='file[]' onclick="choosefiles(this)" multiple='multiple' />
                        <i class="material-icons" id="attach" style="font-size:21px;color:black">attach_file</i><label>Allegati</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />  
            <div>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="seebtn"><p>Files &#9660;</p></button>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="hidebtn"><p>Files &#9650;</p></button>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="unselect" style="display:none;float:left">
                    <span style="color:red">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div id="displayFileNames">
                </div>
                <ul id="myList"></ul>
            </div>
```

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mousemove(function () {
        $('#myList').css('display', 'block');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $("#hidebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
        $("#myList").html('');
        var fileArray1 = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input');
        for (var i = 0; i < fileArray1.length; i++) {
            var files = fileArray1[i].files;
            for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                $("#myList").append("<li style='color:black'>" + files[j].name + "</li>");
            }
        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) != '') {
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'green');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'green');
            $('#displayFileNames').html($("#myList").children().length + ' ' + 'files selezionato');

        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) == '') {
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');
            $('#displayFileNames').append('Nessun File Selezionato');
        };
    });

  });

  function choosefiles(obj) {
        $(obj).hide();
        $('#myList').css('display', 'none');
        $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
        $("#upload-form").append("<input class='file-input inputs' type='file' onclick='choosefiles(this)' name='file[]' multiple='multiple' />");
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
    }

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#unselect').click(function () {
            $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
            $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
            $('#displayFileNames').html('');
            $("#myList").html('');
            $('#myFileInput').val('');
            document.getElementById('upload-form').reset();         
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');

        });
    });
```

```css
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  .divs {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .inputs {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        height: 2%;
        width: 15%;
        opacity: 0;
        background: #00f;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .icons {
        position: absolute;
    }

 </style>
```

```html
 <div>
                <form id='upload-form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                   
                    <div class="divs" id="divforfile" style="color:black">
                        <input id='myFileInput' class='file-input inputs' type='file' name='file[]' onclick="choosefiles(this)" multiple='multiple' />
                        <i class="material-icons" id="attach" style="font-size:21px;color:black">attach_file</i><label>Allegati</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />  
            <div>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="seebtn"><p>Files &#9660;</p></button>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="hidebtn"><p>Files &#9650;</p></button>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="unselect" style="display:none;float:left">
                    <span style="color:red">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div id="displayFileNames">
                </div>
                <ul id="myList"></ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way which I like because it makes the input fill out the whole container. The trick is the "font-size: 100px", and it need to go with the "overflow: hidden" and the relative position.

```
<div id="upload-file-container" >
   <input type="file" />
</div>

#upload-file-container {
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   border: dashed 1px black;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#upload-file-container input[type="file"]
{
   margin: 0;
   opacity: 0;   
   font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It makes sense to make it `position: absolute; right: 0; font-size: <many>px;`

Answer (score 1):

I went for this option which clarifies how to fully customize the browse button by including an handler of the uploaded file name, also customized.
It adds additional fields and client-side controls on them just to show how to include the browse in a "real" form, not just a standalone.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/emiemi/pen/zxNXWR

JS:

```
//click on our custom btn triggers a click on the hidden actual file input 
$("#btnup").click(function(){
   $("#fileup").click();    
});


//changes on the three fields (input, tit,and name) trigger a control which checks if the 3 fields are all filled and if file field is valid (an image is uploaded)
$('#fileup').change(function(){
    var formDOMObj = document.upload;
//here we assign tu our text field #fileup the name of the selected file  
    var res=$('#fileup').val();
    var arr = res.split("\\");
//if file is not valid we show the error icon and the red alert
    if (formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".jpg") == -1 && formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".png") == -1 &&  formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".jpeg") == -1 && formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".bmp") == -1 && formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".JPG") == -1 && formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".PNG") == -1 &&  formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".JPEG") == -1 && formDOMObj.fileup.value.indexOf(".BMP") == -1){
        $( ".imgupload" ).hide("slow"); 
        $( ".imguploadok" ).hide("slow");   
        $( ".imguploadstop" ).show("slow");
        $('#nomefile').css({"color":"red","font-weight":700});
        $('#nomefile').html("The file "+arr.slice(-1)[0]+" is not an image!");
        $( "#bottone" ).hide();
        $( "#fakebtn" ).show();
    }else{
 //if file is valid we show the green alert
    $( ".imgupload" ).hide("slow");
    $( ".imguploadstop" ).hide("slow");
    $( ".imguploadok" ).show("slow");
    $('#nomefile').html(arr.slice(-1)[0]);
    $('#nomefile').css({"color":"green","font-weight":700});
    if (formDOMObj.nome.value!=""&&formDOMObj.tit.value!=""&&formDOMObj.fileup.value!=""){
  //if all three fields are valid the fake input btn is hidden and the actual one i s finally hown
        $( "#fakebtn" ).hide();
        $( "#bottone" ).show();
    }
    }
});


$('#nome').change(function(){
//same as file change but on name field
    var formDOMObj = document.upload;
    if (formDOMObj.nome.value!=""&&formDOMObj.tit.value!=""&&formDOMObj.fileup.value!=""){
        $( "#fakebtn" ).hide();
        $( "#bottone" ).show();
    }else{
        $( "#bottone" ).hide();
        $( "#fakebtn" ).show();
    }
});
$('#tit').change(function(){
 //same as file change but on tit field
    var formDOMObj = document.upload;
    if (formDOMObj.nome.value!=""&&formDOMObj.tit.value!=""&&formDOMObj.fileup.value!=""){
        $( "#fakebtn" ).hide();
        $( "#bottone" ).show();
    }else{
        $( "#bottone" ).hide();
        $( "#fakebtn" ).show();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="upload" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 center">
<!--this is the actual file input, s hidden beacause we wanna use our custom one-->
    <input type="file" value="" class="hidden" name="fileup" id="fileup">
    <div class="btn-container">
<!--the three icons: default, ok file (img), error file (not an img)-->
      <h1 class="imgupload"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></h1>
      <h1 class="imguploadok"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></h1>
      <h1 class="imguploadstop"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></h1>
<!--this field changes dinamically displaying the filename we are trying to upload-->
      <p id="nomefile">Only pics allowed! (jpg,jpeg,bmp,png)</p>
<!--our custom btn which triggers the actual hidden one-->
      <button type="button" id="btnup" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Browse for your pic!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--additional fields-->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group" id="top">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control" name="tit" id="tit" placeholder="I am rubber, you are glue">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="white">All fields are mandatory</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
<!--the defauld disabled btn and the actual one shown only if the three fields are valid-->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" class="btn btn-primary" id="bottone" style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; display:none;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" id="fakebtn"  style="padding-left:40px; padding-right:40px;">Submit! <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style them, but you can't remove the elements that are already there. If you're creative, you can work with that and do something like this:

```css
input[type=file] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: #EEE;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #FFF, #DDD);
    border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    border-radius: .25em;
    box-shadow: inset .25em .25em .25em rgba(255,255,255, .5), inset -.1em -.1em .1em rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    cursor: text;
    padding: .25em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zr1x1m2b/1/

I suggest you play around with this code, remove lines, add your own, do whatever until you get something that looks how you like!

Comment: Doesn't style the "Choose a file" words. [Using `<label>` (as shown by Tympanus)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is semantic and offers complete customizability. Also, this question was asked again a few years later and has much better answers there: [cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button).

Comment: @DanDascalescu You're right! I'm just offering a pure-CSS solution, in case you can't change the HTML with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Just style a normal button however you want, using your favorite CSS.

Then call a simple JS function to create and link a hidden input element to your styled button. Don't add browser-specific CSS to do the hiding part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    button {
        width            : 160px;
        height           : 30px;
        font-size        : 13px;
        border           : none;
        text-align       : center;
        background-color : #444;
        color            : #6f0;
    }
    button:active {
        background-color : #779;
    }
</style>

<button id="upload">Styled upload button!</button>

<script>

function Upload_On_Click(id, handler) {
    var hidden_input = null;
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() {hidden_input.click();}
    function setup_hidden_input() {
        hidden_input && hidden_input.parentNode.removeChild(hidden_input);
        hidden_input = document.createElement("input");
        hidden_input.setAttribute("type", "file");
        hidden_input.style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(hidden_input);
        hidden_input.onchange = function() {
            handler(hidden_input.files[0]);
            setup_hidden_input();
        };
    }
    setup_hidden_input();
}

Upload_On_Click("upload", function(file) {
    console.log("GOT FILE: " + file.name);
});

</script>
```

Notice how the above code re-links it after every time the user chooses a file. This is important because "onchange" is only called if the user changes the filename. But you probably want to get the file every time the user provides it.

For more details, research DropZone and gmail uploads.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one way I recently discovered, with a bit of jQuery

HTML Code:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" style="display:none" id="myFile">

    <a onclick="fileUpload()"> Upload a file </a>
</form>
```

For the javascript/jQuery part :

```
<script>
function fileUpload() {
    $("#myFile").click();
}
</script>
```

In this example, I have put an "anchor" tag to trigger the file upload. You can replace with anything you want, just remember to put the "onclick" attribute with the proper function.

Hope this helps!

P.S. : Do not forget to include jQuery from CDN or any other source

Comment: `display: none` will remove the input from the tab order. [Using `<label>` (as shown by Tympanus)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is far more semantic and less hacky. Also, this question was asked again a few years later and has much better answers there: [cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button).