# Text-link instead of browse form

Tags: html, css, forms, upload

I need to use the plain text to open a browse-window.
When you click on some words (for example 'upload an image') browse-window shows up and you can choose an image you want to upload.
But there should be no forms visible. Just plain text as a link that opens browse-window.

Comment: Please be more clear on what you need, this is not descriptive on what you need at all. Just tell us the problem, and what you actually want to happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-html-input-type-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hide the file upload field and invoke it via JavaScript.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/FhpnF/

Comment: This is very simple and works just how I wanted it to work... thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

ppk wrote a nice walkthrouh called **[Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)**.