# Custom input button show selected file

Tags: jquery, css, html

By default,

```
<input type="file">
```

shows a button and text that says "no file chosen" and then shows the selected file.  I am showing a custom button and thus had to hide the standard button with opacity 0.

How can I show "No file chosen" and show the selected file as well if using a custom button?

Comment: You can't customize file uploads. However, there are other ways around it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize <input type="file">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this TO SHOW THE SELECTED FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#file").change(function(){
        getFileName($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});

getFileName = function(id){
    var str = '';
    var files = document.getElementById(id).files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        str += files[i].name;
    }
    $("#file-name").text(str);
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/W2y8D/