# manipulate html input type file filename in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html input type file control. When I select a file with very big name, it shows complete filename in firefox which causes bad UI. Is there any solution for this problem like changing name etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it this way:

1. Make your html `input file` control hidden and add `onchange` event handler to change selected file name
2. Add a *readonly* html `textbox` control for showing *changed* file name
3. Add html `button` control with `onclick` event handler to trigger file control's click event

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8djed/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="txtFile" readonly="true" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Browse..." onclick="browseFile();" />
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" onchange="setFileName(this.value);" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#file1 {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function browseFile() {
    document.getElementById('file1').click();
}

function setFileName(fileName) {

    /* Manipulate file name here */
    fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    document.getElementById('txtFile').value = fileName;
}
```

Comment: This is not cross browser compatible. You can not send file witch was not set from IO click on file input control.

Comment: AFAIR when you submit standard form `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ... >` the file is not uploaded. I think it is also well documented, but I just assumed this is true and I tread it as bad practice.

Comment: I am not sure if it works or not, but this definitely pointed me in the right direction..But in my real code, I finally used http://uniformjs.com/

Comment: @Nitin uniformjs.com uses opacity:0 trick. Good choice - looks cool.

Answer (score 1):

There is three possible answers I know:

1. You can style size of your input, and then browser cut longer names to given size (with '...' at the end of visible part).
2. You can not change from script the value of file input for security reason. The same is with trigger its click event. So the answer in this case is **No**.
3. You can cover whole file input with *"pseude custom css"*. It is not real input styling but uses some trick with opacity. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file) for more details.