# Change Input File width HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have successfully changed the width and height of input file tag by using different instructions available online. But when I display text on my button the `<input type="file">` does not remain click-able.
This is my HTML code

```
<button id="fileInput">
    <label><strong>Browse</strong></label>
    <input type="file" value="Browse"/>
</button>
```

This is my CSS

```
#fileInput{
    z-index: 9;
    width: 250px;
    height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#fileInput input{
    margin:0px;
    height:50px;
    opacity:0;
    z-index: 99;
    width:350px;
}
#fileInput label strong{
    z-index:100;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

The button is clicked but the `<input type="file">` is not clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to put file input into button but I think it doesn't work. So, you can change the view of input instead of adding button, like accepted answer here: [How to customize <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file)
Or you can do something ,which I advise , like that: 
HTML
<

```
button id="fileInput"><label><strong>Browse</strong></label> </button>
<input type="file" id="input" style="display:none;"/>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#fileInput').click(function(){
    $("#input").click();
  });
});
</script>
```

It is changed form of second answer of the question that I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML

```
<form id="test_form">
  <input type="file" id="test">
  <button>Browse</button>
</form>
```

The CSS

```
input{position:absolute; top:-100px;}
```

The JQuery

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#test").click();
})

$('#test').change(function() {
    $('#test_form').submit();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yboss/WxYLA/1/