# Changing default "choose file" button rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the default "choose file" button in my Rails app. I am using **Bootstrap** and would like to replace the button by one of the **Bootstrap** Glyphicons.

[image]

Here is the `div` of `class` `form-group` that controls the "choose file" button

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/Wez3W/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

Something you need to know is this is not a `Rails` issue - it's an [`HTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file) one. Although it *is* possible, it's more of a hack than a real customization

A good example is [a demo we made here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com/)
(you'll have to register & click on the "profile" button at top right):

[image]

Customizing the `file input` button isn't actually viable as you'd want - you basically need to hide the button & replace it with your own element, which can be then bound to a JS event.

--

**Methods**

**Pavan** posted an epic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/Wez3W) in the comments - props to him!!

We used [`jquery-file-upload`](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for our button - basically allows us to select the file & upload at the same time. Truly amazing:

```
#app/views/your_controller/view.html.erb
<div class="avatar">        
        <!-- New Avatar Upload Form -->
        <%= form_for :upload, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => "avatar"}, :method => :put, url: profile_path(current_user.id), "data_id" => current_user.id do |f| %>
            <div class="btn btn-success fileinput-button avatar" id="avatar_container">
                <%= f.file_field :avatar, :title => "Upload New" %>
                <%= image_tag(@user.profile.avatar.url, :width=> '100%', :id => "avatar_img", :alt => name?(@user)) %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
 </div>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js -> allows to upload directly (no submit)
$('#avatar').fileupload({

    url: '/profile/' + $(this).attr('data_id'),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',

    add: function (e, data) {
        //$(".items .avatar .avatar").prepend('<div class="loading" id="avatar_loading"><img src="<%= asset_path("profile/avatar_loading.gif") %>"></div>');
        //$('#avatar_loading').fadeIn('100');
        $(this).avatar_loading('avatar_loading');
        data.submit();
    },
    success: function (data, status) {;
        $("#avatar_img").fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).attr("src", data.avatar_url).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                $(this).avatar_loading('avatar_loading');
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score -6):

RoR file_field not very customizable. You have to use some "magic".

This [article](http://duckranger.com/2012/06/pretty-file-input-field-in-bootstrap/) solve your problem. But you can also use simple html style.

```
<input type="file" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" />
```

or

```
<input type="file" class="input-file" />
```

Comment: Yes, beware that Chrome does not follow published web standards, so like the old IE days, one needs "special" code "just for Chrome".