# How to set the background color of a file input in IE10+?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-input

Internet Explorer makes the background color of a file upload input gray by default:
[image: Screen shot of IE11's default file upload input]

See: http://jsfiddle.net/L0t48vnf/

How do I make the background color white?

Applying `background: white` CSS works in IE8 and 9, but not IE10 or 11.  See: http://fiddle.jshell.net/L0t48vnf/1/show/

Comment: You may want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file)

Comment: Thanks @Ted.  I did see that question, but I was hoping that there would be a simpler solution for changing the background color.