# How Can I Hide *Only* the Button (Not Entire Element) for the Input Type File in a Django Form?

Tags: python, css, django, input-type-file

I just found this:

[How to customize <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file)

But it hides the entire `input` element. In my case, I'm using Django's `form` and there is text like "no file selected" or after you choose a file, the file name shows up. I want to keep those bits but customize **only** the button part of the input element.

See below for current approach.

[image]
[image]

But I want something like the styled one below but that retains the text in the previous images.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

I guess I should have been clearer. I saw all the other answers out there but my question is different. First of all, I know how to add attributes to the form class. I'm already doing this. Secondly, the images I attached were from my code. In other words, I already implemented the answers in the so-called duplicates.

My question pertains to the text next to the actual button that says "Browse". I want to style the button but **KEEP** the text, because this text is dynamic and changes with user action.

As far as I can tell, the other answers (and my assumption) is that the entire element gets styled with the custom CSS, so when it's hidden or obscured, the text is also hidden.

Given this, can anyone propose an answer?

**Solution**

Thanks to @lmgonzalves, I have realized that my problem was hiding the entire element. I should have just made a button overlay with the custom button like the accepted answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a demo for you, check:

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/uLmLc3xt/5/

The icon is with [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), and here is the code.

HTML:

```
<label id="upload-file-container" for="photo">
    <input id="photo" type="file" name="photo"/>
    <span class="upload-file-wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        <span>Click here to upload file</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
#upload-file-container{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#upload-file-container input{
    position: relative;
    left: 150px; /* Maybe you need to adjust this */
    top: 5px;
}

#upload-file-container .upload-file-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px 0 6px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want. I made a mistake in my code and used `display: none` on the `input` where your method just covers the button part with the custom button. Thanks for putting up with my insolence while I learn ;-) Can you adjust your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Made it!, Also remove the comments to keep it clean.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a id or class HTML attribute via [Widgets.attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) and customize via CSS, just like this:

## Django Form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'id': 'upload'}))
```

## CSS

```
#upload {
 /* ... */
}
```

Helpful links:

- [Base Widget classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#base-widget-classes)
- [Widget.attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

Comment: Like I said in my edit, I don't need advice on how to build Django forms. I have this taken care of and routinely use attributes in the form class to style my forms. Review my edit in my answer and then if you have suggestions, propose them. Thanks.