# Is there are way to give custom styling to browse (upload file) button in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

To maintain consistency within my  application I have to maintain same styling in all browser, but in firefox, styling for browse button is not working at all, it is showing the default styling. Is there a way to change the styling of browse button or not?
Firefox version 50.0.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file

Comment: this link will help you http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html