# Input type file not working if hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to customize my `input type file` button. For that I have put it inside a `span` and set its `visibility` to `hidden`.

```
     <span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn>
        Please choose a file
      <input type="file"style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></span>
```

My problem is that when I click on the span, nothing happen, but when I remove the `visibility: hidden` from the `style`, then the choose file popup is displayed.

How can I get the same result as the `input type="file"` even if it's hidden?

```html
  <span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn>
        Please choose a file
      <input type="file"style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></span>
```

Comment: This seems like a much better way to accomplish what you want, customising the look of the Choose File button : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813384/7852370

Comment: ^ why not do what this guy said :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a `<label>` instead of a `<span>` with a "for" attribute targetting the `<input>`.

```
 <label for="file-input" class="btn btn-default" flow-btn>
    Please choose a file
  <input id="file-input" type="file"style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></label>
```

Comment: Will work without the for in this case since it is wrapped

Comment: @epascarello I'm in the habit because old versions of IE didn't do that properly.

Answer (score 6):

doing it the angular way:

```html
<span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn (click)="fInput.click()">Please choose a file</span>
<input #fInput type="file"style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" (change)="onFilesAdded($event)">
```

- create a local template variable for you hidden input called `fInput`
- add the `click`-event to your span and then click your hidden input
- add `change`-event to your file-input to handle files inside of your template

Answer (score -3):

```
<span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn>
        Please choose a file
      <input type="file"style="display: none;"></span>
```

set the display to none (which hides it and does not reserve space for it)
you won't need positioning either