# Remove label next to <input type="file">

Tags: html, css

I have an `<input type="file">`:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

If no files are selected, then the label says 'No files selected.' In case of a single selected file, the label next to it displays the file name. If more than one file is selected, it says '*n* files selected.'

I was wondering if I could remove that label altogether, so there is only the button left?

Note that the label I'm talking about isn't visible in the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file)

Comment: See especially this answer: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file#answer-16420348)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the input inside a label element, hide the input, and styled the label:

```css
.file-upload {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.file-upload input {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="file-upload">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  Choose Files
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the font color transparent.

```css
#fileToUpload {
  color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```