# Paper Clip option in my leave application form to attach the files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I want to give an options

```html
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
```

paper clip to upload files like image, pdf, doc ... like how we attache in Gmail and WhatsApp like that option I want to give in my leave application form

Instead of choose files, I want option paper clip like this[paper clip option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BGS4.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all or are you just asking us to do it all for you? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-input-type-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below snippet using font awesome.

```css
.fa {
 font-size: 40px!important;
 color: grey;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="file">
 <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>
</label>
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" multiple hidden />
```

Comment: @thejashwinil yes we can, just add `multiple` attribute to the input. Can you please mark as accepted if the answer helped you :)

Comment: @thejashwinil because of this answer, I got down voted. So either you accept this answer as correct answer or I have to remove this

Comment: @thejashwinil there will be a tick mark against my answer, click on that

Comment: I accepted. i tried i got popup msg like you "can accept the answer within one min" like that

Comment: @thejashwinil thanks for accepting the answer, you can ping me when ever needed :)

Comment: Hi @Akhil Aravind I just want to ask another question but I can't ask in this how can I contact you ??

Comment: @thejashwinil you can get my contact info from my SO profile and PM me on mail

Comment: I sent you mail  plzz check